# Django orm. Получить количество объектов

Tags: django, django-orm

Есть три модели A, B, C:

```
Class A:
    some_field = models.CharF...

Class B:
    a = models.ForeignKey('A')
    с = models.ForeignKey('С')

Class C
    some_field = models.CharF...
```

Как средствами Django orm получить количество объектов A принадлежащих C?

Например:
Есть объекты: A1, A2. 
Объект: C1. 
И связи: B1(A1, C1), B2(A1, C1), B3(A2, C1).

В данном примере количество объектов A принадлежащих C будет 2.

Я пробовал так:

```
queryset = A.objects.all()
queryset.values('b__c').annotate(num_results=Count('b__c'))
```

В итоге я получаю, что объекту C1 принадлежит 3 объекта. Таким образом я считаю количество связей, что мне не подходит.

Comment: a = models.ForeignKey('A') - поле обязательно для заполнения? Если нужно количество не нужна совсем первая таблица где A

Comment: да, поле обязательно для заполнения. Не понял вторую часть где вы написали, что не нужна таблица А. В условии проблемы написано: получить количество объектов A принадлежащих C.

Comment: Написал ответ, в таблице B указаны связи. Связь однозначно указывает на ID в таблице A, поэтому запрашивать данные из других таблиц кроме B не обязательно. Но нужно посчитать число уникальных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итоговый код, пояснения будут ниже.

```
filter(c__some_field='значение').values('a').distinct().count()
```

На сколько понимаю модель, есть 3 физических табилицы, 'A', 'B', 'C'.

В таблице 'B' есть все нужные связи, нужны в них только убрать дубли, таблица A как таковая нам не требуется.

Делаем выбор всех записей из таблицы B

```
filter(c__some_field='значение')
```

Дальше расширяем данный запрос, но оставляем одно значение, чтобы убрать дубли

```
.values('a')
```

и убираем дубли

```
distinct()
```

Теперь считаем

```
.count()
```

Зависит от задачи, тоже самое можно сделать через python, получили значение, убрали дубли set, узнали длинну массива.

Answer (score 1):

В данном конкретном случае:

```
a = A.objects.create() # создаём экземпляр А
c = C.objects.create() # создаём экземпляр С
a.c__set.add(c)        # через менеджер связанных моделей добавляем "с" к "а"
a.c__set.filter(c).count()   # смотрим количество всех записей связанных с "с"
```

Можно ещё так:

```
a = A.objects.create() # создаём экземпляр А
c = C.objects.create() # создаём экземпляр С
b = B.objects.create(a=a, c=c) # создаём экземпляр B
B.objects.filter(a=a, c=c).count() # смотрим количество записей
```

А вообще вы можете добавить поле many_to_many в модель:

```
Class A:
    some_field = models.CharF...
    cs = models.ManyToManyField("C")
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не нужно менять условие, так как это упрощенный пример, на самом деле класс В помимо самих связей хранит много информации о связи.
B.objects.filter(a=a, c=c).count() возвращает количество связей, что аналогично тому, что я в вопросе описывал - это не подходит.

Comment: Тогда не понятен сам вопрос. Что нужно получить?

Comment: `a.c__set.add(c)` вы наверное имели в виду `b__set`?

Comment: Попробую перефразировать. Нужно получить количество объектов А используемых в связях к объекту С. Посмотрите еще раз пример в вопросе. В примере связи B1 и B2 одинаковые. означают они то, что объект А1 связан с объектом C1. Связь B3 означает что объект А2 связан с C1. В итоге два объекта А1 и А2 связаны с объектом С1.

Comment: Если нужны сами экземпляры, а не количество, то достаточно убрать count()

Comment: _вы наверное имели в виду b__set?_ Нет, то как написал - правильно.

Comment: нужно количество

Comment: То есть вам нужно количество, но количество не нужно? Что нужно-то? Сформулируйте нормально.

Comment: Мне не нужно количество связей А с С. Мне нужно количество связанных объектов. Почувствуйте разницу. Объектов C может быть сколько угодно, я хочу одним запросом получить количество связанных с С объектов А. Объектов связей B одного объекта А с С может быть миллион, но в моей задаче это означает, что один объект А связан с C.

Comment: Зачем было втягивать меня в такие обсуждения? Я вам и дал способ получить количество всех связей конкретного экземпляра класса А, к конкретному экземпляру класса В. пс: точнее к "С"

Comment: Мне не нужно количество связей госпади( Извиняюсь, что втянул, я уже захардкодил решение, приведу к нормальному виду и выложу ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43890/discussion-between-max-and--).